# SqlCommand replaces "æ" with "?"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, character-encoding

Having issues with a method resetting our database data.

In the command text of the `SqlCommand` we have

```
...
INSERT INTO DA VALUES('lblUsername', 'Æ');
INSERT INTO DA VALUES('lblPassword', 'Ø');
...
```

These special characters are replaced with a `?`.

However if we insert `Æ` with as a parameter

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.Connection = Connection;
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers VALUES(@value)";

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "æ");
```

the `æ` is inserted correctly and is read as an `æ` instead of a ?

How can this be, and is it possible to set a property on the `SqlCommand` to avoid using `SqlParameters` to insert all of our test data ?

database is microsoft sql server 10.0.1600.

table definition

```
CREATE TABLE DA(
KeyWord NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ValueText NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);
```

inserting into table DA

```
INSERT INTO DA VALUES('btnSaveChanges', 'Gem ændrigner');
```

Comment: You should **ALWAYS** use parameters! That's just one more reason (besides avoiding SQL injection and better performance). Don't spend your energy on trying to avoid parameters - **embrace them** and use them - ***ALWAYS***, no exception

Comment: Don't avoid using SqlParameters, because if not you'll need to get your SQL Injection jab.

Comment: not trying to avoid parameters for any methods in the application besides the generate testdata method, which reads our own resetDB.sql file and executes it.

Comment: If those are `NVARCHAR(n)` column, you should use a `N` prefix for your string literals: `INSERT INTO DA VALUES('lblUsername', N'Æ');`

Comment: This changed the "?" to "�"

Comment: whick database are you using ? How is the column DA defined ?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem on the database side. Does INSERT INTO DA VALUES('btnSaveChanges', 'Gem ændringer') give problems as well ?

Comment: the whole thing runs without errors, but when we select the value æ has changed.
the odd thing is if we run this query directly in sql server management, and then selects the value, the æ is a proper æ.
that's why we thought there was a property to be set on SqlCommand to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

If you know your fields will contain non-ASCII characters, perhaps it's better you begin to use `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR` that are "built" for Unicode, so if someone wants an arab Username the system won't give "random" results.

Then:

```
INSERT INTO DA VALUES('lblUsername', N'Æ');
INSERT INTO DA VALUES('lblPassword', N'Ø');
```

See the `N`? It means Unicode string.

Ah... and please, begin using `SqlParameter`. Not using it is like running with scissors. I think **[Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)** is the most important strip an SQL programmer should read.

Comment: This changed the "?" to "�"

Answer (score 0):

You should know ASCII characters how to deal with in SQL.
If you use 'Æ' directly,SQL not know what it is,only know its number in ASCII.
If you use String ,SQL get information directly.